# Stopping linkage against GLIBC turning strftime into __strftime_l

Tags: c++, c, glibc, musl

I have an application which is normally built and executed using GLIBC. One of my users is attempting to use it on a platform built with the MUSL C library (which claims to be GLIBC compatible).

When doing so they are getting an `ldd` symbol resolution failure for `__strftime_l`, which MUSL implements but doesn't actually export as an externally visible symbol.

Is there any way to stop the application build against GLIBC turning functions like `strftime_l()` into to the `__` prefixed versions such as `__strftime_l()` in the run-time resolved symbol table?

Comment: Also, in my simple testing with G++ and GLIBC I can't reproduce this, so if anyone knows under what conditions the decision to use the `__` prefixed versions is taken, that would also be useful to know.

Comment: Neither the [`time.h` header for GLIBC](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/time/time.h) nor [the MUSL `time.h`](https://github.com/rofl0r/musl/blob/master/include/time.h) are doing anything strange with `strftime()`, so I suspect your user's compilation environment.  Try to get this user to give you the preprocessor output from `gcc -E ...`

Answer (score 2):

> MUSL C library (which claims to be GLIBC compatible).

From [musl FAQ](https://www.musl-libc.org/faq.html):

> **Is musl compatible with glibc?**
> ...
>   At present, some glibc-linked shared libraries can be loaded with musl ...
> **all but the simplest glibc-linked applications will fail** if musl is dropped-in in place of /lib/ld-linux.so.2

If you want to support musl, build (and test) a separate version of your application against it. Both you and your users will be much happier with the end result.